# Multi level taxonomy category implementation in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Currently i'm working with Microsoft Azure Search ( PaaS ) services for my product selector implementation.

I made research on azure search & thought of using collections concept but i'm stopped at multi-level hirerchy rendering.

Let me brief about my problem, we have aggregated product data ( meaning multiple aggregator of products ).

In our database having diffrent levels of products hirerchy like 2,3,4 and 8 levels ( taxonomy categorizstion ).

For example

- Chocolate > Cream Chololates > Snickers Chocolate, 150 gm
- Personal Care > Face Care > Face Wash > Family Facewash > Family Facewash Single Pack > HUL > Ponds >  Men Fair & Clean FaceWash - 50 gms
- Sports > Team Sports > Hockey > Sticks > Hockey Stick - 60 cm

Note: Last level is product & we don't know the how many levels product hirerchy limited to.

Problem Statement:

In Front End, on selection of datasource we have to call API to render in frontend.

Here, every datasource is independent of hirerchy levels. ( i.e first datasource may have 5 levels, second one may have 8 levels )

Now problem here is user may select any level by simply searching word ( like Facewash). in other way, top-bottom / bottom-top approach.

If i use the azure search collection approach then i'm not sure of result with reference to level ( i can find only product level ).

can someone suggest best approach to solve this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using Java as API Tech Stack

Answer (score 2):

We don't have a built-in way to handle multi-level taxonomies yet, but you could try the following approach proposed by one of our users: [Multi-level taxonomy facets in Azure Search](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/onsearch/2015/09/09/multi-level-taxonomy-facets-in-azure-search/). To render different taxonomies for different data source types, you could use [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters). The following article explains how to use the Filter and Facet APIs together: [How to implement faceted navigation in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation).

Comment: I'm trying to look at the approach proposed, but this page has been disabled.